# How to display the items in a multi-select box in an infopath 2010 form in a sorted order?

Tags: infopath2010

I have a multi-select field in my Infopath 2010 that looks up values from other lists. I want to display the options in the box in a sorted order. How can I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the data from the SharePoint list directly?
I suggest you create a web service that queries the SharePoint list and sorts the data. You should bind the list control to the result of the web service.